# How to sum entries of different rows in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of orders in MS Access, the leftmost column representing the order ID.

But some orders have more than one type of product, I need to compute the total cost of the order. I know how to get the price of one product (within a line: `[quantity]*[unit price]`) but how do I sum the total product price of multiple rows?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `sum()`.  For instance:

```
select orderid, sum(quantity * unit_price)
from t
group by orderid;
```

This gives the total for each order.  You can change the query to get the total for each product or whatever you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`sum`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/sum-function-ad99511e-b294-44d7-9b8b-7c5f7484fd0b) aggregate function and `group by` the `Products_ID` field, e.g.:

```sql
select t.orderid, t.products_id, sum(t.quantity*t.[unit price]) as price
from YourTable t
group by t.orderid, t.products_id
```

Change `YourTable` to your table name.

Comment: @AntoineP Maybe I misunderstood the question: did you want to sum by `orderid`, or by `orderid` *and* `products_id`?